# Disabling Multiple connection to BLE Peripheral in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am making a BLE peripheral using this Github Code [ble-test-peripheral-android](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/ble-test-peripheral-android/).

I want to disable multiple BLE Connections to my peripheral. I tried using stopAdvertisement() method, but it disconnects already connected device also.

Is there any method available by which I can achieve this?